# php download file не записывая его на сервер

Tags: php

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы PHP сформировал содержимое небольшого файла ( к примеру CSV) массивом или просто строкой, но не записывал его на диск сервера, а сразу отправлял пользователю, причём браузер должен отреагировать именно как на загрузку файла, а не пытаться его отобразить.

Comment: так делать можно

Comment: Ну, ещё бы хоть примерно узнать как это делается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename="test.csv"');

echo 'test;test;test';
```